# How much current do the LEGO motors draw?

Tags: technic, power-functions, motor, electronics

I'm building a project with [Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.org/) and some other electronics driving the LEGO Power Functions M-Motor (8883) and I need to know how much current those motors draw under load.

Has anyone done tests and put together a spec sheet for these motor's electronic characteristics?

<sup>This is my first post here on Bricks.SE!  Hopefully sharing this is welcome.</sup>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*YES!*  Philippe Hurbain (Philo) has put together a great and very detailed write-up on those and many other LEGO 9V electric motors.

You can find it here:  [LEGO 9V Technic Motors compared characteristics](http://philohome.com/motors/motorcomp.htm)

Your current draw for that specific motor @ 9V is:

```
No load:              65mA  
Loaded (3.6 N.cm):    310mA  
Loaded (6.0 N.cm):    480mA  
Stalled (11 N.cm):    850mA
```

---

<sub>I was about to ask this very question when a friend pointed me to this write-up.</sub>
<sup>Hopefully someone else will find it as useful as I did.</sup>

Comment: I found his web site very helpful when I had do find a fitting H-bridge  to control LEGO motors with my arduino

Comment: Can you share the make & model of the H-bridge that you used and where you got it? I have a similar project involving littleBits, See [here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/15798/8175) for details.