# Does LEGO sell a DC relay for Power Functions?

Tags: motor, power-functions, electronics, 3rd-party

I’d like to use a signal from a (5V) [littleBits](https://littleBits.cc) circuit to control some (9V) Power Functions motors.

Does LEGO sell or recommend a DC relay to facilitate this sort of thing?

If the answer is no, I’d welcome any ideas or experiences in how to do this in a way that’s both easy and LEGO-compatible.

Comment: <https://secure.sayal.com/STORE2/View_SHOP.php?SKU=248131> is a relay that can be driven from an Arduino, so I would think it could also be driven by littleBits. But it may require more damage to Lego-supplied wires than you'd like, in order to splice it in.

I don't know if it's viable, but could the littleBits circuit move a small arm side to side? If your hand can control the Power Functions using a remote like <https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58122c01>, then surely a robotic arm could as well.

I don't know that either of these count as easy, or Lego-compatible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LEGO doesn't make something to directly facilitate this type of integration as far as I know. If you can get a [PF extension wire](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/lego-power-functions-extension-wire-8886), you could cut it and directly make the connections to your driver circuit.

[image: PF extension wire]

You can drive the motor using the middle wires of the PF cable (C1 and C2).

For what its worth, I would personally prefer an H-bridge such as [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32925603735.html) over a relay as you get faster switching and can use PWM for speed control among other benefits. You'd power a board like that using a 9V supply and connect the C1 and C2 power lines to one of the outputs. Your 5V logic-level signals would connect to one set of inputs to control the motor.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with H-bridges, but I'm researching the option. Can you tell me if [this SparkFun Motor Driver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14450) would work just as well as the model you mentioned? (I understand that it may be an H-bridge since it is tagged that way.)

Comment: @EJMak I haven't used that exact driver, but it looks like it should do what you want.